# Flume interceptor for kafka message timestamp?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am looking for a custom flume interceptor extracting the timestamp of messages from a Kafka source.

I am happy to try and write it myself, but it seems a common enough idea - I am thinking someone else might have already done it? I just can't find any resources or projects on the internet.

Would appreciate any pointers or links!